# access two database from one spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I have two separate spring boot applications, app1 and app2. One is using mysql other one using postgresql as database source.

I need to access both database in app2 to query some data. Now, it would be easier if I can use the POJO from app1 to query and calculations when I am trying to access aap1's DB from app2. I found online that i can use multiple database in one spring boot application (https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases).

Now, I am exporting the jar file from app1 with all the POJO and other classes and adding it to build path of app2. I am hoping this should work.
Then I tried everything what thay have mentioned in the above link
But I am getting following error

> Description:
>
> Parameter 0 of constructor in  required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your
> configuration.

Is it because I am using jar file instead of actual POJO?

Also, in app1, I am using "Sessionfactory" in DAO, though in app2, I am using cruderepository. Could this be issue?

Also, I have @EnableJpaRepositories annotation in main application.class. Should i comment it?

edit: After making suggested changes, I am getting following error:

> Caused by:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name '' defined in class path resource
> []: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method ''
> parameter 0; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name '' defined in file

Comment: You need define a Bean : entityManagerFactory in your configuration.

Comment: :-) how and where

Answer (score 0):

You need define the Bean like below:

```
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() throws URISyntaxException {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(<your_datasource>);
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(package_to_scan);
    //additional config of factory

    return entityManagerFactoryBean;
}

@Bean(name = "transactionManager")
public PlatformTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) throws URISyntaxException {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
    return transactionManager;
}
```

Comment: I made some progress after implementing your changes, but I am getting other errors now. I have edited the question.